# Who were the original Spears of the Church?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In the Ringed City DLC, you will come across the Spears of the Church, protecting their Lady Filianore. A small boss fight ensues, in which you kill the guardian Halflight and a player NPC. However, when the game first released, there had to be players who did not fight a Spears of the Church covenant member in that battle. Who participated in the battle if there were no covenant members of the Spears of the Church?

Comment: You can test it yourself - just go into offline mode and reset fight at Purging Monument

Comment: @arghtype Why bother asking the question when I could just test everything for myself? There's other parts that are unknown about this that testing myself can't tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPCs wearing the Painting Guardian set are not Halflight. They are, presumably, generic members of the covenant. As far as I know, we don't have any actual lore on them. **EDIT** my memory failed me but we actually have some info on them, from the Church Guardian Shiv, which they use:

> This special throwing blade has a flat tip, and is wielded by
>   guardians of the Church of Filianore.
>
> Guardians of the Church, of whom few remain, watch over Princess
>   Filianore's eternal slumber along with the Spears of the Church.

Halflight himself can be fought if you play offline or if the game cannot find a player to face you. He wears the anticated plain garb set and wields the Frayed Blade, a White Birch Bow and a Knight Shield, and he can use the Divine Spear fragment. You can read a bit of lore about him on the anticated plain garb items description:

> Ordinary garb from an ancient land of sorcery. The gold embellishments
>   betray a faint residue of magic, but this clothing was never intended
>   for battle.
>
> When a mission visited the Ringed City long ago, one of its younger
>   missionaries elected to stay behind. It was he who became the last
>   recorded Spear of the Church.

You can see more info as well as a screenshot of him [on the wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Halflight,+Spear+of+the+Church).

Comment: I thought Halflight was the respawning NPC that throws the magic shurikens at you? Huh...

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to be a covenant member, I've been pulled into the fight when my (white) summon sign was down.
However, if the game has trouble summoning a person, the player black crystals out, or you're playing offline, then a NPC will be summoned instead.  This NPC has massively increased health over a regular player, and I believe they use a spear and shield.